# Running .Net application as administrator makes OpenFileDialog unable to detect network shared folder

Tags: c#, wpf, share

I found out that calling `OpenFileDialog` from an application `running as administrator` will make the dialog unable to detect network shared folders.

Here's my `app.manifest` file, [the purpose is to force the application to always run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/3834).

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Here's the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="built-in" Margin="0,0,308,152" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the CS code:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "txt (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
}
```

Now if there are a few other machines sharing the folders with the machine where this code is run, then the `OpenFileDialog` is unable to detect the share folders.

1. If I don't force the application to run as administrator, then the `OpenFileDialog` can see those shared folders
2. I *can* see the shared folders in file explorer.

Why is this so? Is it possible to be fixed?

Comment: What do you mean? Network shares don't just appear in `OpenFileDialog` either - otherwise you'd see all shared folders from all computers on your domain. You'd have to navigate to a server, eg from the Network node,  to see the shared folders it publishes.

Comment: Your admin account must have access to these shares and be logged on it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,in this case, the network share folders have the explicit permission to appear at other connected machines, and one can know the share folders by looking at the file explorer

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski,the admin account does have accessed to the share folders-- as looking at the file explorer can confirm

Comment: Maybe this helps:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8?forum=windowscompatibility

Comment: @Graviton there's no such *permission*. For those shares to appear in file explorer they were added through a group policy or another mechanism. How were they added?

Comment: @DenisSchaf this is a question about shares, not network drives and the FileOpen dialog, not Folder Browse

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, is it really relevant? Because if I run the application as normal ( not as administrator) , then I can see the shared folders

Comment: In case of mapped drives, those mappings are only for the local user.

Comment: @Graviton obviously. Because that mechanism doesn't seem to work in the elevated profile. Perhaps because it *hadn't* affected that profile. Or because it's a shell extension that doesn't work there?  It's not something that can be "fixed" by code.

Comment: @Graviton what happens when you use any other application, eg Word? Can you see those file shares then? What happens if you start *Word* as an administrator? Those dialog boxes are provided by the OS, not .NET. If the same behaviour appears in other applications, there's not much you can do

Comment: @Graviton *on the other hand* you can modify the default flags used when the Open/Save file dialog appears and control what's shown. That's why it's important to know *how* those shares were published to all users. Maybe it's an item class that can be enabled